# qt and libbluedevil: No Such slot

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to connect to `BlueDevil::Manager::devicesChanged`, but when I run my program I get the error `Object::connect: No such slot Handler::changed(QList<Device*>) in src/handler.cpp:26` How can I fix this error? As far as I can see, changed has the correct type.

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "handler.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Handler handler;

    return app.exec();
}
```

handler.h:

```
#include <bluedevil/bluedevil.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <QObject>

class Handler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Handler();

    public Q_SLOTS:
        void changed(const QList<BlueDevil::Device*> &devices);

    private:
        BlueDevil::Manager *manager;
        BlueDevil::Adapter *defaultAdapter;
};
```

handler.cpp

```
#include <bluedevil/bluedevil.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <QObject>

#include "handler.h"


using namespace BlueDevil;

void Handler::changed(const QList<Device*> &devices)
{
    Q_FOREACH (const Device *device, devices)
    {
        std::cout << qPrintable(device->friendlyName()) << std::endl;
    }
}

Handler::Handler() : QObject()
{
    manager = Manager::self();
    defaultAdapter = manager->defaultAdapter();

    connect(defaultAdapter, SIGNAL(devicesChanged(QList<Device*>)),
            this, SLOT(changed(QList<Device*>)));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
connect(defaultAdapter, SIGNAL(devicesChanged(QList<BlueDevil::Device*>)),
        this, SLOT(changed(QList<BlueDevil::Device*>)));
```

`SIGNAL` and `SLOT` are macros, they can't really be namespace-aware.

If that doesn't work, try:

```
connect(defaultAdapter, SIGNAL(devicesChanged(QList<Device*>)),
        this, SLOT(changed(QList<BlueDevil::Device*>)));
```

... and if that doesn't work, you'll have to put `using namespace BlueDevil;` in your header, and declare your slot with:

```
void changed(const QList<Device*> &devices);
```

and use your original connection. This is a bit sad.

Comment: If I change it to `BlueDevil::Device`, I get `Object::connect: No such signal BlueDevil::Adapter::devicesChanged(QList<BlueDevil::Device*>) in src/handler.cpp:23`

Comment: Added second option, could work depending on exactly how the BlueDevil files are processed.

Comment: `QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
        BlueDevil::Adapter::devicesChanged(QList<Device*>) --> Handler::changed(QList<BlueDevil::Device*>)`

Comment: Last chance, going full circle.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: It's kind of screwed up though. I had hoped for the library to expose the fully-qualified name, but... that's not the case.

Comment: Never put using namespace into headers, always use fully qualified classnames in signals and slots instead.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Unfortunately the signal comes from a library that didn't follow that rule, hence the whole problem.